# SharePoint content database DocStreams table very large

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, content-database

We recently migrated our SharePoint 2007 instance to 2013 using a migration tool. I noticed the disk space for 2013's database partition (300GB) on our SQL Server was running low. I ran a SQL report and saw the DocStreams table was very large (163GB). Is there something I can do to reduce the size of this table through SharePoint CA, such as a setting or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a read here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70390/what-is-the-meaning-of-docstreams-partition it could very possible by related to Shredded storage not being configure in an optimized way. Here is more http://blog.metavistech.com/2013/04/shredded-storage-part-2-how-does-shredded-storage-actually-effect-storage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect the table to grow because the DocStreams table contains all the BLOBs starting with SP2010, whereas in SP2007 they were split between AllDocStreams and AllDocVersions.

If you did your migration/upgrade in place, the Content column from AllDocVersions should be dropped and you can reclaim that space by cleaning up the table (DBCC CLEANTABLE) and shrinking the database (DBCC SHRINKDATABASE) through T-SQL or the SQL Management Studio.

If you migrated your 2007 farm to a new 2013 farm then again, you should still expect the table to be larger in 2013 than 2007, especially if you are storing a lot of document versions.  If you see a substantial difference in size between AllDocStreams+AllDocVersions in 2007 and DocStreams in 2013 then you may have a problem.

Beyond that, you'll need to look at RBS to offload the BLOBs and store them directly on your SAN or NAS.

Comment: I checked the differences between 2007 and 2013. I would put 2007 at about 90-100GB and 2013 at 163GB. I will monitor it's growth from this point on. Thanks for the information. It was very helpful.